# Using range.each vs while-loop to work with sequence of numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, while-loop, range

Total beginner here, so I apologize if a) this question isn't appropriate or b) I haven't asked it properly.

I'm working on simple practice problems in Ruby and I noticed that while I arrived at a solution that works, when my solution runs in a visualizer, it gives premature returns for the array. Is this problematic? I'm also wondering if there's any reason (stylistically, conceptually, etc.) why you would want to use a while-loop vs. a for-loop with range for a problem like this or fizzbuzz.

Thank you for any help/advice!

The practice problem is:

```
# Write a method which collects all numbers between small_num and big_num into 
an array. Ex: range(2, 5) => [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

My solution:

```
def range(small_num, big_num)
  arr = []
  (small_num..big_num).each do |num|
    arr.push(num)
  end

  return arr
end
```

The provided solution:

```
def range(small_num, big_num)
  collection = []
  i = small_num
  while i <= big_num
    collection << i
    i += 1
  end

  collection
end
```

Comment: `[*2..5] #=> [2, 3, 4, 5]`:)

Comment: Don't forget `return` is implicit on the last line of a method.

Comment: What does "premature returns for the array" mean? Your code seems to work as-is.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the comment about `return`! (Didn't realize coming from Python, but that makes sense.) Regarding your second comment, when it pushes to the array, it gives a 'return value' for the array in its current state, so that each time it pushes, it gives an updated return value. That seems strange to me, but maybe I'm over thinking this?

Comment: `arr.push` doesn't return anything, the `range` method you have there won't exit until all the pushing is done. The `push` method does return the object that got pushed to, but as you don't do anything with that return value, it's just ignored. The `<<` method behaves in an identical manner.

Comment: `(2..5).to_a #  => [2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: @tadman Thanks again, you've been very helpful. I'd vote your explanation as useful, except apparently I don't have enough SO points to do that :D

Comment: _"when my solution runs in a visualizer [...]"_ – what kind of visualizer is that?

Comment: @Stefan [link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20range%28small_num,%20big_num%29%0A%20%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%28small_num..big_num%29.each%20do%20%7Cnum%7C%0A%20%20%20%20arr.push%28num%29%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20arr%0Aend%0A%0Arange%282,%205%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=ruby&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of your code:

```
def range(small_num, big_num)
  arr = [ ]
  (small_num..big_num).each do |num|
    arr << num
  end

  arr
end
```

Where the `<<` or `push` function does technically have a return value, and that return value is the modified array. This is just how Ruby works. Every method *must* return something even if that something is "nothing" in the form of `nil`. As with everything in Ruby even `nil` is an object.

You're not obligated to use the return values, though if you did want to you could. Here's a version with `inject`:

```
def range(small_num, big_num)
  (small_num..big_num).inject([ ]) do |arr, num|
    arr << num
  end
end
```

Where the `inject` method takes the return value of each block and feeds it in as the "seed" for the next round. As `<<` returns the array this makes it very convenient to chain.

The most minimal version is, of course:

```
def range(small_num, big_num)
  (small_num..big_num).to_a
end
```

Or as Sagar points out, using the *splat* operator:

```
def range(small_num, big_num)
  [*small_num..big_num]
end
```

Where when you splat something you're in effect flattening those values into the array instead of storing them in a sub-array.

Comment: Or `(small_num..big_num).map(&:itself)`